# Why is Cat quoting individual words in command substitution

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, cat

All,

I'm attempting to use command substitution to keep command line arguments in a file.  My initial thought was to simply place the command line arguments in a single line in a file and then call my command as `command $( cat [arguments-file] ) other arguments`  However, this does not seem to be working for me correctly.

I started to do some debugging, turning on bash debug via `set -x` and the result of the command is

```
command $( /tmp/arg-file ) File.xml
+ command -m '"Manhattan' Item 'MockService"' -P 'Hellp=Value' File.xml
```

My argument file's contents are

```
-m "Manhattan Item MockService" -P Hellp=Value
```

Is anyone able to explain why the single quotes are being added during the command substitution?

Comment: BashFAQ/050 [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not. The single quotes are only visible via `set -x` in order to disambiguate the words to the reader. However, storing command arguments like this is problematic at best. Consider storing one argument per line and [using `read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to generate the command line.